# Parametrized pipeline in GoCD?

Tags: go, jenkins, cd, go-cd

I'm evaluating GoCD if we would be able to use it instead of Jenkins.

Is there any way how to create a parameterized pipeline like parametrized jobs in Jenkins?

In Jenkins, we're using these parameters in some jobs which are executed manually to configure "full-rebuild" of the project:

[image]

This bool value is passed as ENV variable to the job. I have found that GoCD has ENVs but I didn't find if there is a way how such ENV can be selected before manual executing.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. It is possible to parameterize pipelines in GoCD.

Go to pipeline settings -> parameters and add desired parameters. A parameter can be added with a default value, if required.

The next time a pipeline is triggered, one could override the default value with new value and trigger it.
The parameters can be accesses inside pipeline scripts using `#{myParam}`.

More detail here: https://docs.gocd.org/current/configuration/admin_use_parameters_in_configuration.html

Below is a snapshot to set Docker information as environment variables.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9mjwG.png)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply. Is there any way (plugin or extension) how to create a typed parameter? For example, BOOL value is a checkbox?

Comment: As far as I know , typed parameters are not possible.